# Круговая анимация SVG при наведении курсора не работает

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, hover

Я пытаюсь создать анимацию круга SVG, при наведении курсора на кнопки меню навигации, как показано на этом сайте: https://5scontent.com/. На моем сайте кружок появляется при обновлении и затем исчезает.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Alata';
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;


}
.svg-container{
  position: absolute;


}
.svg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1125px;

}
.symbol {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  transition: all 3s linear;
  

}
nav ul li a:hover + .svg-container .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;

}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 2px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <div class="svg-container">
            <svg width="100" height="100" class="svg">
              <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="4" stroke-width="4" class="symbol"/>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Как сделать анимацию бордюра круга при наведении на пункт меню?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [SVG circle animation on hover doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64076821/7394871) от участника  [@Andreas Dahl Trankjær](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14344813/andreas-dahl-trankj%c3%a6r).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64076821/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу одну проблему: у вас есть элемент `div`, как дочерний элемент списка `ul`. Это недопустимо в HTML.
Я бы поместил svg внутри элемента `a` рядом с текстом и сделал

```
a:hover > svg .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

Также значение для `stroke-dasharray` и для `stroke-dashoffset` слишком велико. В вашем случае будет использоваться значение: 50.24. Чтобы узнать, какое значение использовать, вы можете рассчитать периметр круга как `2 * Math.PI * 8`, где `8` - радиус круга.

Для ясности я упростил ваш код:

```css
ul li{display:inline-block; text-align:center;padding:0 1em;}
a{color:white;}
body{background:black;color:white}


.symbol {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dasharray: 50.24;
  stroke-dashoffset: 50.24;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

a:hover > svg .symbol{
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
<a href="#"><span>Work</span><br>
<svg width="23" height="23"  class="svg">
     <circle cx="11" cy="14" r="8" stroke-width="1" class="symbol" stroke="cyan" fill="none"/>
  </svg></a>
  </li>
  <li>
 <li>
<a href="#"><span>Work</span><br>
<svg width="23" height="23"  class="svg">
     <circle cx="11" cy="14" r="8" stroke-width="1" class="symbol" stroke="cyan" fill="none"/>
  </svg></a>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64101682/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>